# Rename sheet while copy to another file

Tags: vba, excel

Im using a macro to copy alot of sheets into one excel file. The macro is from an old project so it needs some tweaking. It looks like this:

```
Sub CombineSheets()

    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sFname As String
    Dim wBk As Workbook
    Dim wSht As Variant

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sPath = InputBox("Enter a full path to workbooks")
    ChDir sPath
    sFname = InputBox("Enter a filename pattern")
    sFname = Dir(sPath & "\" & sFname & ".xl*", vbNormal)
    wSht = InputBox("Enter a worksheet name to copy")
    Do Until sFname = ""
        Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(sFname)
        Windows(sFname).Activate
        Sheets(wSht).Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        wBk.Close False
        sFname = Dir()
    Loop
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

What I need is a way to rename the sheets that I copy, insted of the sheetname from the original file, I would like it to be renamed into the filename, or add the filename to the sheetname.

Answer (score 1):

Not commenting on your old-macro-code (I personally do not like         `Windows(sFname).Activate` but as far as it works it's ok), this is what to do to change the sheet name:

```
Sub CombineSheets()

    Dim sPath As String
    Dim sFname As String
    Dim wBk As Workbook
    Dim wSht As Variant

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sPath = InputBox("Enter a full path to workbooks")
    ChDir sPath
    sFname = InputBox("Enter a filename pattern")
    sFname = Dir(sPath & "\" & sFname & ".xl*", vbNormal)
    wSht = InputBox("Enter a worksheet name to copy")
    Do Until sFname = ""
        Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(sFname)
        Windows(sFname).Activate
        Sheets(wSht).Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        'add this line      --v
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name = "stack" & Replace(Time, ":", "")
        'this line is added --^
        wBk.Close False
        sFname = Dir()
    Loop
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Note that you would probably have an error, if you are looping too fast once you try to save more than one worksheet, because the name would be the same. Thus, it is a wise idea to introducec a counter for the name.